# Glitchy Dragging an object

Tags: codenameone

I have been working on a simple drag feature for my project. I have a touch form which handles all event inputs. My drag implementation works fine, until I move my mouse rapidly. I have heard of getDragRegionStatus() which gets the sensitivity of the event (i could be reading the API wrong). Would this be an option for me? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0OIf.gif)

```
@Override
public void pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y) {  
    if(RectController.top.contains(x[0], y[0])) {
        PersonalizedData.touchTopX = x[0];
        PersonalizedData.touchTopY = y[0];
    }

    else if(RectController.bottom.contains(x[0], y[0])) {
        PersonalizedData.touchTopX = x[0];
        PersonalizedData.touchTopY = y[0];
    }

    if(x.length >= 2 && y.length >= 2 && RectController.top.contains(x[1], y[1])) {
        PersonalizedData.touchTopX = x[1];
        PersonalizedData.touchTopY = y[1];
    }

    else if(x.length >= 2 && y.length >= 2 && RectController.bottom.contains(x[1], y[1])) {
        PersonalizedData.touchTopX = x[1];
        PersonalizedData.touchTopY = y[1];
    }
}
```

I am overriding the pointerDragged with array parameters for multiple touch support. In the end, I will have a top and bottom box, which can be dragged concurrently.
Is there a better way to handle drag events than this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to "select" the currently dragged component in pointerPressed().  Then in pointerDragged, you don't do this check.  You just assume that the item that was selected in pointerPressed is the thing you're dragging.

In pointerReleased, you "unselect" the dragged component.